# How to add "Load More" at the end of ListView with Firebase database (react-native)

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I have a Firebase database that has a lot of components in it, and usually takes a very long time to load at once in a activity in an app that I'm building using Expo.

I was thinking that paginating the activity with a "See More" or "Load More" after each 5 items would make it faster, but I have no idea how to make that. I have tried with: `size: 1, firstVisibleRow: 0, leastVisibleRow: 0, greatestVisibleRow: 0, itemsToShow: 1, rowsToDisplay : 1, expanded: false`, in various places inside the code, but none of them are working.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem using ListView, please? I am attaching the main code below:

```js
import React from 'react';

import {
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  AlertIOS
} from 'react-native';
import {
  Constants
} from 'expo';
import firebase from './firebase';

const StatusBar = require('../Firebase/StatusBar');
const ActionButton = require('../Firebase/ActionButton');
const ListItem = require('../Firebase/ListItemEventsNew');
const styles = require('../Firebase/styles.js');

export default class Events_new extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      //size: 1,
      //firstVisibleRow: 0,
      //leastVisibleRow: 0,
      //greatestVisibleRow: 0,
      //itemsToShow: 1,
      //rowsToDisplay : 1,
      //expanded: false
    };
    this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('-Events');
  }

  getRef() {
    return firebase.database().ref();
  }

  listenForItems(itemsRef) {
    itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {

      // get children as an array
      var items = [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        items.push({
          headline: child.val().headline,
          _key: child.key
        });
      });

      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items),
        //itemsToShow: 1,
        //rowsToDisplay : 1,
        //expanded: false
      });

    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.listenForItems(this.itemsRef);
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      View style = {
        styles.container
      } >
      <
      StatusBar title = "Events" / >
      <
      ListView dataSource = {
        this.state.dataSource
      }
      renderRow = {
        this._renderItem.bind(this)
      }
      enableEmptySections = {
        true
      }
      style = {
        styles.listview
      }
      />

      <
      /View>
    )
  }

  // <ActionButton onPress={this._addItem.bind(this)} title="Add" /> pt butonul Add

  _addItem() {
    AlertIOS.prompt(
      'Add New Item',
      null, [{
          text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Add',
          onPress: (text) => {
            this.itemsRef.push({
              title: text
            })
          }
        },
      ],
      'plain-text'
    );
  }

  _renderItem(item) {

    const onPress = () => {
      AlertIOS.alert(
        'Complete',
        null, [{
            text: 'Complete',
            onPress: (text) => this.itemsRef.child(item._key).remove()
          },
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            onPress: (text) => console.log('Cancelled')
          }
        ]
      );
    };

    return ( <
      ListItem item = {
        item
      }
      onPress = {
        onPress
      }
      />
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect 
**the scroll reaches the bottom** => **fetch more data** => **change state** => **show more row**

`onEndReached={this.loadMoreActivities}`

```
loadMoreActivities = () => {
  // fetch data here
}
```

You should use `debounce` for optimization. Keyword `debounce lodash`

Comment: Thank you. It sounds like the right algorithm, but how do I do that? Can you give me more hints? After your answer, I found some documentation on the *onEndreached*, but I'm not sure how to put it together.

Comment: Will try tomorrow. Thank you very much for the help.